# How does "use" in Laravel work - e.g. use Auth, use DB

Tags: php, laravel

I did some googling about use and namespaces in PHP, but after doing some research I did not find the answer.

`use [foo]` means use foo class from its relative directory (Laravel will know which file to use).

But I don't see any Auth or DB classes relative to my working file. Are there any aliases I don't know about?

Additionally, in `view.blade.php` why I can run `Auth::check()` without saying `use Auth`?

Comment: [Namespaces in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: And `Auth` is set as an alias in Laravel, meaning that Laravel has already handled the mapping to the namespaced Auth class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the `config/app.php` file.

Here you'll find an `aliases` section which shows where all those shorthands are defined.

As for your views, presuming you're using Blade, then when these are compiled by Laravel those aliases are also made available.

Comment: When I install "parsedown" package with composer I can say "Use parsedown" too. Are there another place defining aliases?

Comment: Parsedown (presuming you mean erusev/parsedown) looks like it doesn't put its class into any subfolders, so there you're able to just `use Parsedown`. This is handled by autoloading - you might find this useful for more on that: https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading